# castear un entero de un tamaNo diferente

Tags: punteros

Creee tres funciones basicas suma resta multiplicacion que devuelven punterios genericos:

```
static void* fn_suma(int, int);
static void* fn_resta(int, int);
static void* fn_multiplicacion(int, int);
```

con su implementacion; luego trato de que una funcion puntero pueda acceder a ello y me aparece

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

de esta forma:

```
int (* p_fnc)(int, int) = fn_suma;
void* pfnc_x = NULL;
pfnc_x = (int *)p_fnc(8, 18);
printf("[%d]\n", *(int *)pfnc_x);
```

y no he encontrado material que me ayude a ver en donde me he equivocado.
Chicos. Todavia intento solucionarlo revisando material si encuentro alternativa les aviso.
Quisieran que me hechen una mano. Gracias

Comment: Hola, Buen dia. Para este primer dia de problema estudiare todo lo relacionado a los punteros. En la tarde les comento que progreso tengo con el tema. Gracias nos vemos

Comment: SeNores, encontre la respuesta. Me alegra que hayan tenido la oportunidad de leerme y por sus contribuciones. Si quieren la respuesta solo avisen.

Comment: Si tienes la respuesta, puedes auto contestarte y de paso, aceptar la respuesta como correcta.